# What is the second derivative of $g(x) = max(x-l, 0) / x$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $g(x) = \max(x-L, 0) / x$, what is the derivative of g w.r.t. x?

My result is $g''(x) = \delta(x-L)/x -2\theta(x-L)/x^2 + 2 \max(x-L, 0) /x^3$.

But my result doesn't agree with the book I am reading. What should it be?

The result written in the book is $-\frac{2L}{x^3} \max(x-L, 0)+\delta(x-L)/x$.

Comment: What was the result written in the book?

Comment: Consider it piecewise. Its $0$ when $x\leq l$ and $(x-l)/x$ on $x >l$. What are the derivatives of these now?

Comment: The result written in the book is $-\frac{2L}{x^3}max(x-L, 0)+\delta(x-L)/x$

Comment: Your question is about the derivative and you give the answer for the second derivative. Which one do you want?

Comment: @BernardMassé second derivative

Answer (score 1):

**Your result is the correct one.**

To check that the answer in the book is false you can compute the derivative when $x>L$.

In this case the derivative is the second derivative of $1-\frac{l}{x}$ i.e:
$$-\frac{2L}{x^3}$$
but if you use the book result you obtain:
$$-\frac{2(x-L)}{x^3} \neq -\frac{2L}{x^3}$$